# why is Matsya Vibhava of Vishnu-Narayana also referred to as Ekasrngatanu?

Tags: vishnu, agamas, pancharatra

In the *Ahirbudhnya samhita* of *pAncarAtra Agamas*, the thirty nine *vibhavas* of ***SrIman nArAyaNa*** are listed. Here we observe that ***Matsya*** *Vibhava* (incarnation) of ***Vishnu-nArAyaNa*** being referred to as ***Ekaśṛṅgatanu***.

- What does ***Ekaśṛṅgatanu*** mean?
- What is the reason behind the equation of ***Ekaśṛṅgatanu*** with ***Matsya*** *avatara*?

Comment: found answer, posted it.

Comment: Do you have an english translation of the pancaratra agamas somewhere?

Comment: Which samhita are you looking for? @user1952500

Comment: The Anirudha Samhita in particular.

Comment: Aniruddha Samhita is currently unavailable in English AFAIK @user1952500

Comment: Thanks SudarshanaSuri for the confirmation. I was hoping someone would have it.

Comment: @user1952500 no problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Ekaśṛṅga*** means *"single-horned"*.

> [ekaśṛṅga एकशृङ्ग](http://sanskritdictionary.com/eka%C5%9B%E1%B9%9B%E1%B9%85ga/45032/1)
>
> Definition: mfn.   having but one horn, unicorn

Thus, ***Ekaśṛṅgatanu*** means *single-horned one*. The equation is thus in reference to ***Vishnu-nArAyaNa***'s ***Matsya*** *vibhava* which is single-horned.

According to [Matsya Purana](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.135349/2015.135349.Matsya-Purana-A-Study_djvu.txt) <sup>[looking for exact verse to cite]</sup>

> Boat, Rope and Anchor— The king was also told that the boat which would come to him was the Ship of the Vedas (Veda navam), that he should stock there all the seeds of living creatures (Sattia hjani), that he should pilot the boat by a rope to be supplied by the divine Fish and **tie it to its horn** to be protected by the glory of the Divine Creator Things happened as was predicted and all the assurances given were fulfilled The rope was the Cosmic Serpent and the Fish to whose liom the boat was anchored in the midst of the watery flood was the Divine Creator himself

*Reference for word meaning is also available at  [Wiktionary](https://sa.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%8F%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%99%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%97)*

Comment: @Pandya reference to dictionary is in place

Comment: Good, I have bit edited the answer, btw, if further details regarding Matsya Avatar narrating the horn from text like Matsya Purana can be included